# Como deixar um site responsivo com ou sem bootstrap?

Tags: html, css

Estou fazendo meu primeiro site pra um cliente, faltando apenas deixar o site responsivo.
Eu queria saber como posso fazer isso? a maioria dos tutoriais por ai é com bootstrap, porém eu iniciei e terminei o site sem bootstrap, tem como começar a usar assim pelo final mesmo, ou eu teria que refazer tudo?

Comment: Com Bootstrap, se vc já tivesse conhecimento, poderia implementá-lo ao site, mas, sem conhecimento, sugiro refazer toda a estrutura do site e ir adicionando ele. Sem Bootstrap, vc pode fazer ficar resposivo utilizando técnicas de CSS, como **flexbox e media queries**. Aconselho a vc a aprender estas técnicas de CSS primeiro e depois utilizar frameworks CSS como Bootstrap, Bulma, Materialize, etc... para saber o que eles fazem por detrás dos panos. Tem bastante material deste tipo no google e youtube.

Comment: Completndo a resposta do LeAndrade. Imagina que vc é um alfaiate, ai vc desenha, corta e costura um terno inteirinho, ai o cliente veste o terno e fala que ficou pequeno... Olha o tamanho da M... Agora imagina que cada página que vc fez é um terno diferente e vc fez 5 ou 6! Alguma coisa vc vai conseguir aproveitar, mas provavelmente seria melhor começar novamente do 0 pois a responsividade envolve a parte estrutural do HTML, vc precisa de um Grid etc.  De uma estudada aprofundada antes de começar a refazer. Estude muito FlexBox ou Grid Layout. Depois vc pode pensar em usar um framework...

Answer (score 2):

Com ou sem bootstrap você precisa entender sobre o conceito de grid

**O que é um Sistema de Grid?**

No caso de você ser um novato em sistemas de grid CSS, vamos começar com uma rápida definição. Em termos básicos, um sistema de grid é uma estrutura que permite o conteúdo ser empilhado verticalmente e horizontalmente de uma forma consistente e facilmente gerenciável. Além disso, o código de um sistema de grid é um “*project-agnostic*”, dando-lhe um elevado grau de portabilidade, de modo que, possa ser adotado em novos projetos.

**Componentes Básicos**

Sistemas de grid incluem dois componentes principais: linhas e colunas. Linhas são usadas para acomodar as colunas. Colunas compõem a estrutura final e envolvem o conteúdo real. Alguns sistemas de grid irão incluir containers, que servem para envolver o layout.

leia mais em: https://tableless.com.br/entendendo-sistemas-de-grid-css-do-zero/

Answer (score 2):

Use Media Queries. As Media Queries definem condições para que o CSS seja utilizado em cenários específicos. Se essas condições forem aprovadas, ou seja, se o dispositivo de adequar a todas as condições estabelecidas na sua Media Querie, o CSS será aplicado.

```
// Extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px)
@media (max-width: 575.98px) { ... }

// Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)
@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767.98px) { ... }

// Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991.98px) { ... }

// Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199.98px) { ... }

// Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }
```